# Ubuntu 18.04 - cannot change brightness of screen and cannot resume from suspend

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, screen, brightness

I've installed Ubuntu Budgie alongside with Windows and Linux Mint on my laptop a few months ago, but haven't been using it since then. A few days ago I crashed Mint and decided to begin using Ubuntu. But soon I found out that I cannot change brightness of the screen - I don't even have any slider or option in settings. I've tried a few different ways of overcoming it (described below), but with no result.

I've tried installing `nvidia` drivers instead of those provided by xorgs, but they didn't work properly (`nvidia-settings` displayed nothing) or desktop didn't appear after booting depending on version I installed, so I removed them.

I've tried adding `"acpi_backlight=vendor"` to grub defaults for Linux.

I've tried [this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/), but I don't have anything in my /sys/class/backlight/ folder. I also don't have Graphics page in System Settings. However, I've tried creating files in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, but it resulted in GUI not starting after logging out.

I've tried using `xrandr`, but that's the message I got when I try to list outputs:

`randr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`

I've tried installing `xbacklight` and using it, but it has no effect, it even doesn't show any error.

I've tried creating some scripts, which was decribed in other posts (sorry, I opened so many pages that I cannot find it) but it all also failed, as it demands backlight drivers. It seems to me I don't have them and I don't know how to obtain them.

Two days ago I also realized that after suspending, when I press the power button, laptop begins to work (I can hear it), but screen remains black. As internet adviced, I tried installing other kernels using `ukuu` (now I have 4.18) but again, with no result.

I write it all in one question as I suppose these two problems are connected.

My graphics card is Nvidia GeForce GTX 950M, my laptop is MSI GL62 6QE.